# Robotics Studio CCR/DSS and .NET Micro Framework Compatibility

Tags: ccr, robotics-studio, .net-micro-framework

I hope that I did my homework on this one, I'm basically asking for a second opinion.

My understanding is that the CCR and the DSS (and the rest of the MS RDS tools) cannot and will not run on a device that supports the .NET Micro Framework.

My goal is to, as much as possible, use the DSS to talk to devices but some of the devices that I would like to talk to (such as Camera modules) will be connected to a Panda II Micro Framework board. Therefore, unless I write a DSS-Compatible service on the Panda II board that publishes the camera, I will not be able to access the Camera's feed through most other means.

Frankly I find that the .NET MF does 50% of the solution great and MS RDS does the other 50% great - I just wish that I could have the DSS running on the .NET MF.

Am I mostly correct in my research? Have I missed something?

My project involves creating a home automation system and I find the MS RDS compatible devices either difficult to find (especially for some purposes) or very expensive. While .NET Micro Framework compatible devices will give me a humidity sensor for around $20 and other great capabilities for just as low a price. And I don't have the know-how to create a hardware solution, I just have ideas and I'd like to make a prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.

The type safety built into the heart of CCR relies on generics which are, of course, not supported on .Net MF

It would be possible to write an interop layer for DSS, but if all you want is one camera that's a lot of work or not much benefit. An alternative approach would be to write a DSS service that implements the webcam contract and communicates to the camera on the panda board using a protocol that makes sense to you, either a custom protocol of your own devising, or just write a simple web server and use it as an ip camera (there is already an ip camera service)